# Find the complex integral on the boundary of a triangle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be the boundary of the triangle $\{0<y<1-x,0<x<1\}$, with the usual counterclockwise orientation. Evaluate the following integral

(a) $\int_\gamma \text{Re }z\,dz$

(b) $\int_\gamma \text{Im }z\,dz$

(c) $\int_\gamma z\,dz$

I worked out the problem and found out that

(a) $\int_\gamma \text{Re }z\,dz$ = $\frac{i}{2}$

(b) $\int_\gamma \text{Im }z\,dz$ = $-\frac{1}{2}$

(c) $\int_\gamma z\,dz$ = $0$

I don't know whether my calculation is right or wrong. I was wondering that since the corner points are not included, would it be still same?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write

$$\oint_C \text{Re}(z)\,dz=\oint_C x\,dx +i\oint_C x\,dy \tag 1$$

The first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ vanishes since $\int x\,dx=\frac12 x^2$ and $C$ is a closed contour.

In addition, Green's Theorem in the plane guarantees that the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is equal to the area enclosed by $C$.  Therefore, we conclude that

$$\oint_C \text{Re}(z)\,dz=i\,\,\text{Area enclosed by }\,\,C=\frac i2$$

---

From Cauchy's Integral Theorem, $\oint_C z\,dz=0$.  Therefore, we find immediately that

$$\oint_C \text{Im}(z)\,dz=i\oint_C \text{Re}(z)\,dz=-\frac12$$

And we are done!

Comment: thank you very much for your concise solution. Is the area enclosed by C 1? Isn't it $\frac12$ and is last equation right i.e., $\oint_C \text{Im}(z)\,dz=-i\oint_C \text{Re}(z)\,dz$, is there any negative sign?

Comment: Good catch.  I've edited accordingly.